# how to config terminal in vscode like this?add terminal auto has its terminal name

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I have many projects and I open some terminals of different projects. What should I do to know which terminal belongs to which project?

Look at the picture. I want to config its name. When I add a new terminal, it has an automatic name every time.

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/appearance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
firstly, you click at powershell at vs code
second: you click rename: then you enter your project.

good luck

[image]

Comment: thanks to my brother! thats not my expect,what i wanna have is that when i add a new terminal it would change its name auto not need i rename it manu